# Остановить запущенную функцию js скрипта

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нажимая на кнопку ***"Старт"***, запускается функция и рандомно выводит текст в двух блоках.

В кнопке меняется при клике цвет и текст. Каким образом её можно остановить ?

```js
cube0 = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']

cube1 = ['t2', 't3', 't4']

function random() {
  random_cube_0 = cube0[Math.floor(Math.random() * (cube_0_length))];
  random_cube_1 = cube1[Math.floor(Math.random() * (cube_1_length))];
}

$("#start").click(function() {
  function go() {
    random()
    $('#bones-objects').text(random_cube_0)
  };
  setInterval(go, 50)

  function go1() {
    random()
    $('#bones-objects0').text(random_cube_1)
  }
  setInterval(go1, 50)
  $("#start").text("Стоп").toggleClass("btn-danger")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row main-block-objects">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div id="bones-objects"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div id="bones-objects0"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прочитать хотя бы минимум документации по функции [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: В этом и был мой вопрос, понять что мне нужно заменить или исправить. Спасибо, я сам нашёл ответ, сделав setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Исправил, извините за беспокойство глупым вопросом.

```
$("#start").click(function() {
var interval = setInterval(function() {
        random()
        $('#bones-objects').text(random_cube_0)
        random()
        $('#bones-objects0').text(random_cube_1)

})
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log(interval)
}, 5000);
```

});

Comment: лучше бы вы сделали подсчет числа срабатываний, и при достижении нужного количества останавливали бы выполнение